# How can I find $E(\mathbb F_{17})$ for the elliptic curve $E:$ $y^2=x^3+c$ where $c$ is any element in $\mathbb F_{17}^*$?

Tags: number-theory, elliptic-curves

This was left as an exercise in a seminar in my college. I tried to figure it out myself, but haven't been able to make any progress thus far. I don't think it should need any non-trivial result (or should it?) like Mordell's theorem, but I really have no clue. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: the map $\mathbb F_{17}^*\to\mathbb F_{17}^*$ which sends $x\mapsto x^3$ is a bijection.

Comment: How does that help?

Comment: adrija, using that result it is easy to determine how many choices of $x$ there are for a given value of $y$. Infinity included. You may still need to determine the 2-torsion and/or 3-torsion to figure out the group structure. This assuming you were also asked to figure that out and not just count the number of $\Bbb{F}_{17}$-rational points.